# change textbox value depending on combobox selected item

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

I'm trying to make my c#, wpf application change the value in a textbox accordingly with the value in a combobox using 'IF' statements.

The idea is that if the Gender combobox has 'Male' selected, then the sex.Text should show 'm'. 
If Gender has 'Female' selected then sex.Text should show 'f'. But unfortunately the sex textbox will show nothing on the first selection. But afterwards, it keeps showing the opposite of what I want it to. E.g when I select female it displays 'm' and vice-verse, as if it's having a case of delayed action.

Here's the event:

```
    private void gender_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (gender.Text == "Male")
        {
            sex.Text = "m";
        }
        if (gender.Text == "Female")
        {
            sex.Text = "f";
        }
    }
```

Any clue on how to make this work?

I'm guessing this may have something to do with the winforms SelectedIndexChanged event being replaced by the SelectionChanged as it's wpf equivalant.

Clearly I just may not know how to use it.

Help much appreciated.

Comment: Er... `System.Windows.Controls.ComboBox` doesn't have `TextChanged` event.

Comment: Try 'ComboBox Selected Value changed event' and set the values for Male and Female as 1 and 2, Based on the values u can set the textbox value

Comment: Sorry. Just fixed that. I typed it in rather than copy and paste. My mistake.

Comment: @Offer `SelectionChanged` uses `SelectionChangedEventArgs` not `TextChangedEventArgs`. Any chance you could just copy-paste the code to ensure there's no difference between the two that could have some impact on your problem?

Comment: decPL copied and pasted. Sorry again..

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I can't add a coment, so here go a suggestion.

Try to get the current value this way:

```
private void gender_SelectionChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
 {
        var currentText = (sender as ComboBox).SelectedItem as string;

        if (currentText.Equals("Male"))
        {
            sex.Text = "m";
        }
        if (currentText.Equals("Female"))
        {
            sex.Text = "f";
        }
 }
```

I coded just here, so sorry for any mistyping.

Comment: Hie. Um i got an error on ".Text" after SelectedItem. here it is: Error 22 'object' does not contain a definition for 'Text' and no extension method 'Text' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) . I'm thinking it's my fault because i mistyped the event up here. It's supposed to be SelectionChangedEventArgs instead of TextChangedEventArgs.

Comment: I edit the answer a moment ago. The SelectedItem represents the item that was put in the ComboBox. If it is a string, just do a cast from the object.

Comment: Thanks. It ran this time round. But i got the classic "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." exception thrown when I tried to select a gender. Pointing at this piece of code: if (currentText.Equals("Male"))...

Comment: Do you really have itens on your combobox when the event is fired? What is the type of item that you have? Is it just a string like "Male" or do you have any other object type?

Comment: Appologees For the delay. My combobox has 'Male' and 'Female' in it. It's all in xaml though.

Comment: First of all, I agree to @Sheridan, you don't need to use code behind to this stuff. You can do all using triggers. I would sugest you to try his code. If you would like to keep this way, here is the XAML that I used with the code behind above.  
`<ComboBox Name="gender" SelectionChanged="gender_SelectionChanged">
            <System:String>Male</System:String>
            <System:String>Female</System:String>
</ComboBox>`
- Okay, I don't know how to code on a comment. HAHA

Answer (score 1):

If you want to write WPF properly, then you *really* need to learn XAML. You don't need any code to do what you want (except for the data properties of course). You can do it with just a couple of `DataTrigger`s:

```
<StackPanel>
    <ComboBox Name="ComboBox" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" />
    <TextBox>
        <TextBox.Style>
            <Style>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SelectedItem.Text, 
                        ElementName=ComboBox}" Value="Male">
                        <Setter Property="TextBox.Text" Value="m" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SelectedItem.Text, 
                        ElementName=ComboBox}" Value="Female">
                        <Setter Property="TextBox.Text" Value="f" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </TextBox.Style>
    </TextBox>
</StackPanel>
```

This is of course assuming that you have a collection [`DependencyProperty`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752914%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to data bind to in the code behind:

```
public static DependencyProperty ItemsProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Items", typeof(ObservableCollection<Gender>), typeof(YourWindow));

public ObservableCollection<string> Items
{
    get { return (ObservableCollection<string>)GetValue(ItemsProperty); }
    set { SetValue(ItemsProperty, value); }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your items in the `ComboBox` are just strings, you could use this:

```
private void gender_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    sex.Text = gender.SelectedValue.Equals("Male") ? "m" : "f";
}
```

It looks like the `Selected`-type properties on the `ComboBox` reflect the new selection when the event fires, but the `Text` property still reflects the previous selection.

Comment: This almost worked... Problem is that when run, it only shows 'f'. On the up side, it show's it on the first selection though.

Comment: Apologees for the delay. I meant your second guess. It never changes to 'm' regardless of whether I select "Male" or "Female". The only part where our code differs is that "TextChangedEventArgs" in your example is "SelectionChangedEventArgs" in mine. It was my fault for mistyping it in the first place. But if your code ran, then I'm guessing mine should be identical to yours...

Comment: I kinda played around with your code a bit and found a little alternative that does the job. Just confirm for me that this is okay. " sex.Text = gender.Text.Equals("Male") ? "f" : "m"; " I had to use '.Text' instead of '.SelectedValue' and I swapped "m" and "f"s positions because it kept showing 'f' when I select 'Male' and vice-verse. I'm not sure if that's how it's supposed to work though. Just confirm for me please.

Answer (score 0):

I would change your code to this:

```
private void gender_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)  
    {
        if (gender.SelectedValue == "Male")
        {
            sex.Text = "m";
        }
        if (gender.SelectedValue == "Female")
        {
            sex.Text = "f";
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I am late to answer, but see the following to get the right coding:

In xaml page:

```
    <ComboBox x:Name="Gender" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" IsEditable="True" TextBoxBase.TextChanged="Gender_SelectionChanged"/>
    <TextBox  x:Name="Sex"    Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="3"/>
```

In the C# page:

```
    private void Gender_SelectionChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Sex.Text = Gender.Text.ToLower().Substring(0, 1);
    }
```

Good luck